# Why is Flask-Admin throwing this exception when attempting to edit a model?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

The exception is `AttributeError: 'StringField' object has no attribute 'wrap_formdata'` and it seems to only happen when I go to create or edit either of the following two models from the Flask-Admin dashboard:

```
class Experiment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    property_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                            db.ForeignKey('property.id'),
                            index=True,
                            nullable=False)

    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='Draft')

    title = db.Column(db.String)
    meta = db.Column(db.String)
    seed_uri = db.Column(db.String)

    targets = db.Column(postgresql.JSON)
    variations_json = db.Column(postgresql.JSON)

    variations = db.relationship('ExperimentVariation',
                                  backref='experiment',
                                  cascade='save-update, merge, delete')

    def __repr__(self):
        repr_fmt = '<Experiment {id}, {property_id} {name}>'
        return repr_fmt.format(id=self.id,
                               property_id=self.property_id,
                               name=self.name)


class ExperimentVariation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    experiment_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                              db.ForeignKey('experiment.id'),
                              index=True,
                              nullable=False)

    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    title = db.Column(db.String)
    meta = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        repr_fmt = '<ExperimentVariation {id}, {experiment_id} {name}>'
        return repr_fmt.format(id=self.id,
                               experiment_id=self.experiment_id,
                               name=self.name)
```

I'm wondering if there's some complication with the relationships. I can provide the `Property` model if that helps, but in a nutshell most of that model is just providing relationships between other models including the Experiment model.

A quick Google doesn't appear to turn up similar issues. More than likely I'm overlooking something obvious or perhaps not fully grokking the relationship API.

Also I've included the full traceback below for clarity:

```
ERROR [ranksci] Exception on /admin/experiment/edit/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1969, in edit_view
    form = self.edit_form(obj=model)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1256, in edit_form
    return self._edit_form_class(get_form_data(), obj=obj)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 212, in __call__
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/form/__init__.py", line 16, in __init__
    super(BaseForm, self).__init__(formdata=formdata, obj=obj, prefix=prefix, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.process(formdata, obj, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/projects/ranksci-app/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 119, in process
    formdata = self.meta.wrap_formdata(self, formdata)
AttributeError: 'StringField' object has no attribute 'wrap_formdata'
```

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the column called `meta`: it would seem this value is being munged with some other value that wtforms cares about. Not precisely sure where this is happening. I'll update once I've tracked it down. My initial feeling is this should be fixed in flask-admin/wtforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured out the root cause of this problem: Flask-Admin constructs a form class, which by default subclasses a WTForm's Form class, from each SQLA model. This is all well and good unless one of your columns matches one of the arguments the WTForm's constructor takes, for instance `meta`.

The logic for constructing said classes is [here](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/bff1f96024880b1dde6aeadb38e5a6bdf7065abc/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/form.py#L442). I'm not completely sure what the correct fix for this is, however it does seem like a situation Flask-Admin needs to handle either technically or socially. For instance, it would be handy to know ahead of time that `meta` shouldn't be used as a column name since this problem will occur.

It's worth pointing out that the following variables are also accepted by the WTForm's Form constructor and thus should probably be avoided as well: `formdata`, `obj`, `prefix`, and `data`.

A technical solution to this problem might be to construct a set of these variable names and then explicitly check for them when creating the model forms in the above Flask-Admin code. Then a warning of some kind could be generated or the `name` variable could be altered such that it was prefixed with `_` or some such. This isn't a perfect solution because of course WTForms could change its API in the future.